# Unable to Resolve '@stytch/react' Module Error Despite Successful Installation and Cache Cleaning

Tags: javascript, error-handling, module, node-modules, stytch

I'm utilizing the Stytch B2B option and have attempted to set up the 'magicLink' using their 'UI components'. However, I am encountering an error message that says:

```
Cannot find module '@stytch/react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
Yet, the module does indeed exist in 'node_modules/@stytch/react'
```

Same thing for `@stytch/vanilla-js`

dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
...
    "@stytch/react": "^5.0.0",
    "@stytch/vanilla-js": "^1.0.2",
...
  },
```

Custom UI

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Products } from '@stytch/gitvanilla-js';
import { StytchLogin } from '@stytch/react';

const config = {
  emailMagicLinksOptions: {
    loginExpirationMinutes: 30,
    loginRedirectURL: 'https://example.com/authenticate',
    signupExpirationMinutes: 30,
    signupRedirectURL: 'https://example.com/authenticate',
  },
  products: [Products.emailMagicLinks],
};

export const Login = () => {
  return <StytchLogin config={config} />;
};
```

I've deleted and re-installed it, cleared the 'npm' cache, and re-installed the dependencies, but nothing seems to work.

I'm not sure what I might be missing.